# Can I use express-basic-auth with a GCP cloud function?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, basic-authentication

`@google-cloud` uses express with an interface like this:

```
exports.Entry = (req: Request, res: Response) => { }
```

So there is no `app` object to use

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'admin': 'supersecret' }
}))
```

with. What can you do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to create an object for the `app` first and set the GCF handler.

```
const express = require('express');

// Create an Express object and routes (in order)
const app = express();
app.use('/users/:id', getUser);
app.use('/users/', getAllUsers);
app.use(getDefault);

// Set our GCF handler to our Express app.
exports.users = app;
```

You can check this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/express-routing-with-google-cloud-functions-36fb55885c68) for reference.